# FFMPEG FLV to 3GP more than 176x144 size

Tags: ffmpeg, flv, 3gp

I am converting my.flv to my.gp3 with this command

```
ffmpeg -i my.flv -acodec libamr_nb -s 176x144 -ar 8000 -b 120000 -vcodec h263 -ab 10.2k -ac 1 my.3gp
```

but size of my flv is 320x240 and I am trying change 176x144 to 320x240 but getting 3gp file with 0kb , how can I do that and get my.3gp file with same size like my.flv

And one more thing , the my.flv is product of converting from my.swf(vide) , if you know some command which will do swf->3gp with same size it would be better .
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I used your command line with my copy of ffmpeg (bundled with Xuggler) and it produced perfect output. There were some warnings but it didn't affect the output.

```
E:\media\New>ffmpeg -i red5.flv -acodec libamr_nb -s 176x144 -ar 8000 -b 120000 -vcodec h263 -ab 10.
2k -ac 1 my.3gp
FFmpeg version SVN-r24930-xuggle-4.0.896, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 25 2010 23:41:31 with gcc 4.2.4 (TDM-1 for MinGW)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/xuggle --extra-version=xuggle-4.0.896 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/home/Paul
/code/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/build/native/i686-pc-mingw32/captive/usr/xuggle/include --extra-ldfl
ags=-L/usr/home/Paul/code/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/build/native/i686-pc-mingw32/captive/usr/xuggle/
lib --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3
lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libspeex --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-lib
opencore-amrwb --extra-cflags=-mno-cygwin --extra-cflags=-fno-common --extra-ldflags=-mno-cygwin --e
xtra-ldflags=--out-implib --enable-w32threads --enable-memalign-hack
  libavutil     50.24. 0 / 50.24. 0
  libavcore      0. 6. 0 /  0. 6. 0
  libavcodec    52.86. 1 / 52.86. 1
  libavformat   52.78. 3 / 52.78. 3
  libavdevice   52. 2. 1 / 52. 2. 1
  libavfilter    1.38. 1 /  1.38. 1
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
[flv @ 007d9f20] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000/1) -> 11.99 (12000/
1001)
Input #0, flv, from 'red5.flv':
  Metadata:
    duration        : 1
    width           : 480
    height          : 360
    videodatarate   : 0
    framerate       : 12
    videocodecid    : 4
    filesize        : 27733
  Duration: 00:00:01.33, start: 0.167000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: vp6f, yuv420p, 480x368, 11.99 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
[buffer @ 007de2f0] w:480 h:368 pixfmt:yuv420p
[scale @ 007dee70] w:480 h:368 fmt:yuv420p -> w:176 h:144 fmt:yuv420p flags:0xa0000004
Output #0, 3gp, to 'my.3gp':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.78.3
    Stream #0.0: Video: h263, yuv420p, 176x144, q=2-31, 120 kb/s, 12k tbn, 11.99 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press [q] to stop encoding
[h263 @ 006cc200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 10 times
[h263 @ 006cc200] warning, clipping 2 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h263 @ 006cc200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 3 times
[h263 @ 006cc200] warning, clipping 2 dct coefficients to -127..127
[h263 @ 006cc200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
[h263 @ 006cc200] warning, clipping 2 dct coefficients to -127..127
[h263 @ 006cc200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame=   13 fps=  0 q=1.6 Lsize=      24kB time=1.08 bitrate= 182.3kbits/s
video:23kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 3.130478%
```